# How to keep the Bootstrap pop over enable until the form is filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap pop over to display the form. Pop over is coming fine. but it is not allowing to enter any value in it, overlay is getting hide, when the focus from the link is out.

Is there any fix for this. I want to keep the pop over until my focus is out of pop over.

Requirement:

1. On focus of link, pop over should get displayed.
2. And it should allow me to enter the form elements.
3. if focus is out from the form, then form should get hide.

this is what I tried:

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html : true,
        content: function() {
          var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
          return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z824fn6b/253/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 simple things, both on JS(final code mentioned below) 
[Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/z824fn6b/254/)

1. Add a delay to your popover function
2. Then override the default `mouseleave`and `mouseover` events adding few lines of code.

Final updated JS Code below -

```
$(function(){
    //added
    var originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave;
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave = function(obj){
      var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
          obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type)
      var container, timeout;

      originalLeave.call(this, obj);

      if(obj.currentTarget) {
        container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.popover')
        timeout = self.timeout;
        container.one('mouseenter', function(){
          //We entered the actual popover – call off the dogs
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          //Let's monitor popover content instead
          container.one('mouseleave', function(){
            $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
          });
        })
      }
    };

    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html : true,
        delay: {show: 50, hide: 400}, //added
        content: function() {
          var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
          return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
        }
    });

});
```